# How to run multiple terminals in parallel to run scrappers written in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, multiprocessing

Let's suppose, I want to open 5 bots at the same time (those bots in python, one the same as the other) that are running web scraping:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Edge("msedgedriver.exe")
options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
driver = webdriver.Edge(options = options)

driver.get('https://youtu.be/Ykvf7oR0JBY')
time.sleep(30)
driver.close()
```

Using Java, can I use multprocessing (or something like that, multithreading for example) to run the 5 bots in parallel at the **same** time? these bots in different terminals working completely in **parallel**!!

if possible, how can i do that?

if not, what language or framework would be able to perform this task? that's possible in any language?

Comment: what have you tried, and where did you get stuck? have you taken a look at the `multiprocessing` or `subprocess` libraries (part of stdlib)

Comment: @Aaron multprocessing in python is not able to run more than one code or file at a time, nor create multiple terminals, since other languages ​​are able to run more terminals (or several files LITERALLY AT THE SAME TIME (in the same second)), I just need to know how to do this

Comment: @Kaan 
in python it's not possible, just one after the other, I need it to be at the same time, in different terminals

Comment: If your question is as simple as "How do I run multiple terminals at the same time", consider looking into Tmux. Tmux is an open-source terminal multiplexer for Unix-like operating systems. It allows multiple terminal sessions to be accessed simultaneously in a single window. If you refactor your code to accept arguments from the command line, you can call multiple running, and provide the corresponding arguments.

Comment: `os.system("start cmd")` will literally open another terminal in windows, so your statement is incorrect. there are plenty of ways to do just about anything, but you need to be clear what you mean when you describe your problem.

Comment: You'd just want threading... one driver per browser... In Java I usually use a class that extends SwingWorker for that.  (It's a nice little abstract class for threading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html )  You should remember, though, that browsers tend to take all the resources they can get.  If you can get away using something like HTMLUnit, you can run many many more threads.

Comment: @Aaron but that just opens a cmd (you ignored everything else), I would need it to be running the 5 bots, in a way that it's not one after the other (which doesn't work) I need it to be literal at the same time even if it's ones 3 seconds later, but all the solutions they show me work like queue, it just makes the first bot have to have its entire code read completely to execute the next one. 
this is not actually the code i am using, because it is webscraping 1000 lines, and it needs to be fast, which makes it impossible to wait until all lines are executed

Comment: I asked in some discord groups and they told me that it wouldn't be possible in python, only languages ​​like C and Java for example, so I'm lost on this question, I imagine it's actually not possible.

Comment: @lucaslima the point of my comment using `os.system` is that it's totally possible for python to launch a new executable (while still continuing to run itself). I think you may be confusing some of us with referring to a "terminal", and we are not understanding eachother. I have just posted an example of using multiple instances of selenium to scrape files in parallel that I cut and pasted from an old project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @Aaron's comment, Python's standard library has both process-based and thread-based parallelism support through [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) respectively. The documentation gives plenty of examples on how to execute functions in parallel. So you wouldn't need to run something else to execute Python processes in parallel, since the Python processes would already run in parallel by themselves.

Regardless, you can execute multiple command line programs in parallel using `xargs` from GNU Findutils by specifying the `--max-args` and `--max-procs` command line options (for more see the [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html)). With that, you could have a list of websites you wish to scrap in a text file and them do

```bash
cat links-to-scrap.txt | xargs --max-lines=1 --max-procs=4 python scrapper.py
```

and evidently adapt your Python scrip to take the link to scrap from `stdin`.

Just to make it very explicit: `xargs` is language independent, so you can execute any CLI application in parallel with it. There are many useful examples of that in its man page.

Finally, as a bonus, you may wish to take a look at executing programs concurrently, not in parallel, using asynchronous programming with [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) or [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/), but I don't know how you could make that work with Selenium (though if you only wish to get the source code from websites you could use `aiohhtp` with [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)).

Comment: unfortunately python is only able to run one file at a time, it is not able to run 5 at the same time on different terminals (what I need it to do)

Comment: Did you see the links I mentioned? Yes, it is able to, and I have done so before. Just look at the first example from [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) in the Python documentation. In any event, using `xargs` you can run as many terminals as you like.

Comment: Just to be clear: `multiprocessing` and `threading` execute a single _command_, but can run multiple _processes_ or _threads_ at the same time, in parallel. You don't need to call the program multiple times for it to run in parallel.

Comment: well you certainly need to call something multiple times.... whether that's a script, a class, method... each thread needs to do something.  As a side note, "Async" is not threading.. it's just non-blocking calls to a particular thread.  That's not helpful for Selenium as your actions have a specific sequence. (and wire protocol is designed to be synchronous... request/response)

Comment: Yes of course you do, by "call  the program" I meant run `python not.py` multiple times in different terminals as the OP meant (I think). Also, you can scrap multiple URLs concurrently using asynchronous programming. After all, isn't the whole point of concurrency for independent processes not to block one another?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I stripped down out of an existing project of mine of using multiple instances of selenium to scrape webpages... It is not impossible as you have been lead to believe. I'm frankly not sure where that notion would come from in the first place. Python is a first class programming language with the capability to do just about anything. Compiled languages may be faster than interpreted languages, but there's no inherent limitation to Python only running a single process.

```py
import re
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from selenium import webdriver


def worker(q: Queue, manifest: dict, mod_dir: str):
    #### setup chromedriver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {
        "download.default_directory": mod_dir,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": "false",
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    }
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
    #download ChromeDriver persuant to your version of chrome
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.

    #### iterate over links
    for i, link in iter(q.get, None):
        driver.get(link);
        # time.sleep(1)
        source = driver.page_source
        #### find the Project ID
        m = re.search(r"<span>Project ID</span>.*?<span>(\d+)</span>", source, flags=re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
        # ... 
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    manifest = {...} #some config data
    links = [...] #links to scrape
    n_workers = 4
    
    q = Queue()
    procs = [Process(target=worker, args=(q,manifest)) for _ in range(n_workers)]
    for p in procs:
        p.start()
    for i, l in enumerate(links):
        q.put((i,l))
    for p in procs:
        q.put(None)
    for p in procs:
        p.join()
```